# Prestashop Product Details Page Goes to Wrong URL

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I found my product detail page url in prestashop build by appending product id first.

From Below Docs.
http://doc.prestashop.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20578464

i found that my prestashop product id_product=27 becomes 27-ipod-nano-green

But in my prestashop configuration it is redirect to another url.

Link creates properly as per this docs. But when i click on it to open product detail page it redirect to another url (i think goes to find category url with the same id) and end up with 404 not found error and for some product it landing on category page.

I am using prestashop version 1.6.1.12

Please suggest me how can i solve my issue or which files are related for this changes.

Below are my current configurations:

```
Schema of URLs:

Route to products : {id}{manufacturer}-{rewrite}
 Route to category : {id}-{rewrite}
 Route to category which has the "selected_filter" attribute for the "Layered Navigation" (blocklayered) module : {id}-{rewrite}{/:selected_filters}
 Route to supplier : {id}__{rewrite}
 Route to manufacturer : {id}_{rewrite}
 Route to CMS page : content/{id}-{rewrite}
 Route to CMS category : content/category/{id}-{rewrite}
 Route to modules : module/{module}{/:controller}
 Route to CMS page : content/{id}-{rewrite}
 Route to CMS category : content/category/{id}-{rewrite}
 Route to modules : module/{module}{/:controller}
```

Comment: What are your seo preferences? And url? Usually the product page ends in .html, without it it would work as a category page. With the default configurations.

Comment: Yes. My Product Page not Ending with .html. I think it work as a category page. Tell me how can i make product page with .html ??

Comment: In Preferences -> SEO what are you current Schema of urls for all routes? Edit the question with that information, please.

Comment: You should change you Route to products to {id}-{rewrite}-{manufacturer}.html or {id}-{manufacturer}-{rewrite}.html depending if you want the product name or the manufacturer name first in url

Comment: Yes..When i change **Friendly URL** to **yes** and  **Accented URL** to **yes**. And then put default value in **Route to products :** **{category:/}{id}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html**. Its working fine. Pls.. tell me how can i combine manufacturer name in product url. Otherwise thaks a lot for giving me a right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. i added manufacturer name in product url by adding  **Route to products : {category:/}{id}-{manufacturer}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156664/discussion-between-vijay-rami-and-sadlyblue).

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
{category:/}{id}{-:id_product_attribute}-{rewrite}{-:manufacturer}.html
```

Regards